# Best practice email confirmation in MEAN app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, email-validation

### What is the best email confirmation flow for user and for app?

Some variants:

#### a) The most simple variant, but not the best.

1. User send signup form.
2. On backend I send link with random hash to users email. In parallel I save this user to db with the `active:false`, `hash: hash` fields.
3. user click link
4. on backend I check link for hash, try to find user with hash. If user found in db, I change `active` to `true`.

   **Flaw:** What if email isn't correct or error happened during send? How I can handle it? I can't

#### b) We can handle all errors and display it to user, but very slow variant

1. User send signup form.
2. On backend the first of all I save this user to db, then I send link with random hash to users email and if it was sent correctly( no errors) **only then**, I send response.
3. if error happens, I send error response to client, so he know that letter didn't send.
4. probably, I need to delete this user from db

   **Flaw:** Process of registration is really slow. It takes about 20 seconds

#### c) The best variant, I think

1. User send signup form.
2. On backend I save the user to db.
3. If no errors, I send response to user. In parralell send link with random hash to users email.
4. user get response, if no errors , redirected to page e.g. `/last-step` with text `check your email...` Also on this page I'll show link, which will allow to send email confirmation again (e.g. every 3 mins)

   **Question:** How I can recongize on backend from whom this link was clicked? Where to store temporary info about this user on client?

Comment: I'd go with `C`, and I'd use `JWTokens` for token authentication. That is signed token, in which you may store user_id, or any other data required for his authentication. Although remember, it's not encrypted, therefore it's always available for the public view - so do not store passwords, or any confidential data there. https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: This seems to be a question, not about implementation, but about usability and responsiveness. This question might be better off on the [User Experience Stack Overflow](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) site.